# Filter with regex inside Observable

Tags: typescript, observable, angular7

I want to filter with  insensitive case.
I tried many way but not success. 
Its works with includes but no success if i apply new regex inside filter or i use match

```
  filterProperties() {
    this.propertiesService.getProperties().pipe(
      map(
        //  (properties) => properties.filter(property => property.title.includes('LON')))
         (properties) => properties.filter(
           property => {
           const title = new RegExp('london', 'i');
           property.title.match(title);
          }
          )),
        tap(x => x)
      )
      .subscribe(
        properties => this.properties = properties
      );
  console.log(this.properties);
  }
```

Comment: All of your filter conditions are false, because the callback doesn't *return* anything...

Comment: you're right. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter`'s callback should return something, with `includes` it works because you return `true/false` value of `includes`, arrow function returns single line automatically if `{}` are missing, that's your case here `property => property.title.includes('LON')`, with `regexp` it doesn't work because you didn't return something,  to fix it add return

```
properties => properties.filter(
  property => {
  const title = new RegExp('london', 'i');
  return property.title.match(title);
 }
))
```